# Abstracting out the OWIN authentication in an MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, owin

I'm working on a solution with others where we have built on a Visual Studio Web Project using MVC (5 I think) and WebApi2.0.

The nature of the solution is that it has 2 DALs, one of the DALs uses SQL to access another applications database, the other DAL uses entityframework codefirst to manage our applications database. There is also a service that is associated with the project so we have done our best to adapt the entire solution into a 3 tier pattern. This means there is a project that contains our BusinessLogic and both our service and our Controllers use it to access the DAL.

So all that out of the way...We are now adding in authentication on the web side. We were stuck for days until we really just embraced Microsoft's default project structure with the OWIN authentication. The downside is that we now have a separate User database that is essentially coupled with the Presentation/Web layer of the solution.

Is there any way to keep all the convenience of the default OWIN authentication in the MVC project AND abstract it out into the LogicLayer? I can't post what we've worked on, but needless to say it's failed every time because we are really struggling to identify what is being done for us behind the scenes (one example is the [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(AlarmAggregator.Startup))] annotation). This annotation alone makes me think we will NOT be able to abstract it out.
I know I'm asking to have my cake and eat it too, but I was hoping someone had some insight if it was possible.

At the very least we were hoping there was a way that we could combine our internal database and our user database? I think this would have to happen at the context level? Would it be as simple as pointing our web.config at our internal context?

Comment: Google for custom Identity (that's really what you are using) setups using SQL Server and you will likely understand how you can do what you want

Comment: @cFrozenDeath custom ASP.NET Identity? Is it a custom storage provider? Is Identity an OWIN thing or an ASP.NET thing?

Comment: Identity is the membership provider (authorization/authentication) that runs on the OWIN middleware. Identity can be configured to the storage provider of your choice (SQL Server, MySQL, etc etc etc). OWIN is as ASP.NET thing. Highly recommend you to look at some basic OWIN tutorials/documents

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned what those 2 databases are, I assume they are not user databases and out of context. Focusing on the user identity storage, yes its going to be a separate entity unless you are using ADFS, LDAP or something. I would discourage you from building your own identity solution, rather look out for something more widely used and accepted because its a security topic.

Take a look at [Thinktecture Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3). Its an OpenId Connect based open source solution built in .NET. It comes with its own database, supports same domain SSO, cookie based authentication and supports open id connect. It also supports federated authentication if you want to hookup a ADFS. Its also possible to do social sign in integration with it.

I have integrated .NET, Java and PHP solutions in production to the same instance and everything is fantastic and seamless.

You can host it as a separate service. You can register known clients (your apps and services), their incoming and redirect urls, including post logout Urls, so your application can seamlessly reach out and come back from identity server. The Identity Server comes with all the middleware you would need to protect your APIs and web applications. It also provides REST endpoints for getting and validating access tokens amongst others.

You can also set different scopes to specify the scopes against which a request can be processed.

Much of what I am talking about has directly to do with oAuth 2.0 specs so probably you can read a little about it [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) if you are not aware of it.

Using a typical oAuth Flow, (e.g implicit flow or authorization code flow), hooking up the right middleware in the Owin pipeline, and decorating your API resources with [Authorize] attribute, your Application will redirect to the identity server page where the user can login. Your APIs(the protected resource) can specify if they are expecting for a specific Scope, when a token is presented and allow to accept/deny your request based on that.

The client registration ensures that only known clients are accepted by identity server(as applications are generally internet facing) and you can either use the MembershipReboot component, also from Thinktecture(also opensource) as your identity store or write your own implementation of a "user service". There are way too many extension points available to play with and you can practically customize everything including the look and feel of the identity server pages to match the UI scheme of your client applications. There is IUserService(to plugin your own user store, ViewLoader to customize UI, CORS policy service to specify allowed origins per client, certificate based TokenSigningService to sign tokens(access/refresh tokens), ScopeStore, ClientStore, TokenHandleStore(to store scopes, client configurations, tokens), ClaimsFilters to filter what claims are included when a token is issued, which is helpful when you use external providers which might return more information that you need to store or provide)

I can go on for ever here but like I said its something available for use and I am using it for multiple applications in production, you can give that a try.

You can have it up and running in 30 mins on your local machine with both Identity Server and MembershipReboot databases setup. The support is very good from the authors and this is a very widely accepted solution for user authentication and authorization.

For example, securing a WebAPI is super simple:

1. decorate your APIs with `[Authorize]` and or `[ScopeAuthorize]` based on your need
2. This tells the API to go and check if you got something setup for Authorization in the owin pipeline.
3. In Owin startup just use:

   app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()
   {
   Authority = "http://your-idserver-url"
   });

Yes that is all the change you need in your WebAPI. There is a separate way to setup open id configuration for MVC based web applications but that is anyway available in the documentations with sample code.

The documentation is pretty easy to follow and the server is easy to setup. It takes away all the complexity from your App and services so you can focus on what you want your App to do rather than worrying about handling Authentication and Authorization in each of your Apps or services.